# how to aggregate grouped objects in pandas using information from subgroups?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas's groupby().agg() allows performing operations on each group in a data frame. However, I can't figure out how to using subgroup information within agg().

For example, I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': ['G1','G1',  'G1',  'G2',  'G2', 'G2'], 
'b': [True, False, False, True, False, False], 
'c': [1,    2,     3,     1,    2,     3]
}
```

I want to divide `df` to groups based on `'a'`, and then for each group to find the ranking of each value in `'c'` that has `'b'==True` within all the `'c'` values. In the case above, the output should look like:

```
'a'   'ranking'
 G1       1
 G2       1
```

This is easy to do in a for loop, but this should be doable in one line. Anyone has ideas?
Thanks!! Rotem

Comment: will it work `df[df.b]` ?

Comment: I'm looking for the ranking of the True value within all the values. Coincidentally the True value is 1, but if you replace `c` with `c:[0,1,2,0,1,2]` the output should remain the same as above.

Comment: should you change the b as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use apply instead of agg, similar to what Wen suggested but with a different function. apply receives data frames as input from the groupby object, while agg only receives series from the groupby object. 
`df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: np.searchsorted(x.c, x[x.b==True][c]))`